# MSIS5004: The WSFederationPassiveEndpoint address is not configured on the relying party trust identified by the endpoint

Tags: asp.net-mvc, adfs

I am developing a web application using asp.net MVC 5 that is integrated with ADFS. After login to ADFS using credentials I get this error:

Microsoft.IdentityServer.RequestFailedException: MSIS7012: An error occurred while processing the request. Contact your administrator for details. ---> Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.SecurityTokenService.EmptyOrMissingWSFederationPassiveEndpointException: MSIS5004: The WSFederationPassiveEndpoint address is not configured on the relying party trust identified by the endpoint 'https://xxxxx.xxx.com'. It is required to process the current request.

please advise ..!

Comment: Just came to know that i have to correctly set endpoint configuration in ADFS settings